# How can I build a query in my controller action that indexes parent models, with parent-specific children nested using foreach loops?

Tags: laravel-8

I'm currently trying to create an index of cards depicting rooms, with their associated desks indexed within them, using nested foreach loops within the view:

```
<div class="grid grid-cols-1 gap-3 ">
                    @foreach ($rooms as $room)
                        <div class="bg-white text-center h-auto">
                            {{ $room->name }}
                            <div class="m-3">
                                <div class="lg:grid lg:grid-cols-6 gap-3">
                                    @foreach ($desks as $desk)
                                        <div class="bg-red-200 text-center h-10">
                                            Desk {{ $desk->id }}
                                        </div>
                                    @endforeach
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    @endforeach
                </div>
```

The Room controller index action currently looks like this:

```
class RoomController extends Controller
{
    public function index()
        {
    
            return view('index', [
                'rooms' => Room::all(), 
                'desks' => Desk::all()
            ]);
        }
}
```

I'm aware that Desk::all() is indexing all desks for all rooms. Instead, I need to build a query that indexes desks belonging only to each room. My model relationships are defined as:

Room hasMany desks

Desk belongsTo room

Any help would be much appreciated, thanks.

Answer (score 1):

instant doing like rooms::all and desk::all use can simply run an eloquent query like:-

```
room::with("desks")->get();
```

note :-you need to make a relation in your room model with name "desks" like this :-

```
public function desks(){
    return $this->hasMany(desk::class);
}
```

and your foreign key name must be like model name +_id

Answer (score 0):

Managed to solve this. Desk::all() worked as I wanted to make all desks available at controller level. Instead I added a where clause to the nested foreach loop to filter by room_id:

```
<div class="grid grid-cols-1 gap-3 ">
                    @foreach ($rooms as $room)
                        <div class="bg-white text-center h-auto">
                            {{ $room->name }}
                            <div class="m-3">
                                <div class="lg:grid lg:grid-cols-6 gap-3">
                                    @foreach ($desks->where('room_id', $room->id) as $desk)
                                        <div class="bg-red-200 text-center h-10">
                                            Desk {{ $desk->id }}
                                        </div>
                                    @endforeach
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
```